# how to compute cosine similarity between words for a large DocumentTermMatrix

Tags: r, parallel-processing, tm, cosine-similarity

I have a large tdm, for which I need the cosine similarity for every term with every other term. Standard procedures are not helping as I am getting the following error.

```
 Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1162.4 Gb
```

Since I am a novice with parallel processing in R, I am unable to use it to get the job done.Below is a small dataset. Any help would be great.

```
 library(tm)
 data("crude")
 tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(crude)
```

The ideal output needs to be as follows.

```
  Word   Related_Word  cosine_distance
  oil        opec                   0.5
  oil        spill                  0.3
   .....................................................
   .....................................................
```

Comment: Try the package quanteda, it uses sparse matrix.

Comment: @José - I tried the following code and it gave me an error as below.

     Error in asMethod(object) : 
    Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105

Comment: These posts should get you where you need to go. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41721431/cosine-similarity-of-2-dtms-in-r/41723921#41723921, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41721431/cosine-similarity-of-2-dtms-in-r/41723921#41723921, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750519/r-calculate-cosine-distance-from-a-term-document-matrix-with-tm-and-proxy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: Calculate cosine distance from a term-document matrix with tm and proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750519/r-calculate-cosine-distance-from-a-term-document-matrix-with-tm-and-proxy)